# How to break mainloop in Tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, using

In my project, I needed to use Tkinter and Dialog
So I did coding, but I cannot break Tkinter.mainloop
How can I break Tkinter.Mainloop?

Comment: Please read about and provide us with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `your_instance_variable_name.destroy()`.

Answer (score 1):

To stop `mainloop` from running you must destroy the root window.